# why the curve have been into a straight line in image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

[image: picture1]

[image: picture2]

I used a camera to take pictures of an ellipse and use opencv to get the contour. You can see the picture1, the vertex part of the ellipse is not a cruve but a straght line. why?Does the low resolution of the picture cause curve to a straight line? 
Also, you can see picture2, the staigh line doesn't happen at the vertex part of the ellipse.Is the straight line just parallel to X axis and Y axis?  why?

Comment: Yes, **the low resolution of the picture cause curve to a straight line**, and for the second case the curvature is not same as the first one so it seems to better fit.

Comment: @ZdaR Thanks for your comment.The curvature is not same,this is my question, wht not the same. Because it is the same ellipse. I just change the angle.

Comment: Then maybe your X and Y dimensions are not equal.